# 複数の差集合を求めるプログラムがかけません

Tags: c

集合Aと集合Bの差集合を求めるプログラムは作成できたのですが、複数の差集合を求めるプログラムが作成できません。

例えば集合A{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}と集合B{0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18}の2つが存在するとして、
その差集合A-B={1,3,5,7,9}のような結果となるプログラムは以下のように作成しました

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* size個 のデータが入っている配列を 配列の先頭から順に出力する */
void printIntArray(int a[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i=i+1) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");   
}

/* na個 のデータが入っている集合に x と等しい要素があるかどうかを判定する \ */
int memberOf(int x, int a[], int na)
{
    int i,result=0;
    for(i=0;i<na;i=i+1) {
        if (x==a[i]) {
            result = 1;
        }
    }
    return result;

}

// 集合a と集合b の和集合を集合c として求める
// na, nb は，集合a, b の要素数
// 返り値は，集合c の要素数
int diff(int a[], int na, int b[], int nb, int c[]) {
    int i, k;
    k = 0;

    // a を順に走査
    for (i = 0; i < na; i = i + 1) {

        // a[i] が条件を満たすならば
        if ( !memberOf(a[i], b, nb) ) {

            // c に追加
            c[k] = a[i];
            k = k + 1;
        }
    }
    return k;
}

int main(void)
{
    int SA[1024] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int SB[1024] = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18};
    int SC[1024] = {};
    int length=diff(SA,10,SB,10,SC);

    printf("集合A: \n");
    printIntArray(SA, 10);
    printf("集合B: \n");
    printIntArray(SB, 10);

    printf("集合A-B: \n");
    printIntArray(SC, length);

    return 0;
}
```

しかし、全体集合U={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A={1,3,5,7,9},B={1,2,3,4,5},C={0,2,4,6,8}となったとき、
A、B、Cの補集合を求めるプログラムを作成する方法がわかりません。
(複数の差集合を求めることができません）

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* size個 のデータが入っている配列を 配列の先頭から順に出力する */
void printIntArray(int a[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i=i+1) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");   
}

/* na個 のデータが入っている集合に x と等しい要素があるかどうかを判定する \ */
int memberOf(int x, int a[], int na)
{
    int i,result=0;
    for(i=0;i<na;i=i+1) {
        if (x==a[i]) {
            result = 1;
        }
    }
    return result;

}

// 集合a と集合b の和集合を集合c として求める
// na, nb は，集合a, b の要素数
// 返り値は，集合c の要素数
int diff(int a[], int na, int b[], int nb, int c[]) {
    int i, k;
    k = 0;

    // a を順に走査
    for (i = 0; i < na; i = i + 1) {

        // a[i] が条件を満たすならば
        if ( !memberOf(a[i], b, nb) ) {

            // c に追加
            c[k] = a[i];
            k = k + 1;
        }
    }
    return k;
}

int main(void)
{
    int SU[1024] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int SA[1024] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
    int SB[1024] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int SC[1024] = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8};
    int SD[1024] = { }; 
    int length=diff(SU,10,SA,5,SD);
    int length1=diff(SU,10,SB,5,SD);
    int lenght2=diff(SU,10,SC,5,SD);

    printf("全体集合U: \n");
    printIntArray(SU, 10);
    printf("集合A: \n");
    printIntArray(SA, 5);
    printf("集合B: \n");
    printIntArray(SB, 5);
    printf("集合C: \n");
    printIntArray(SC, 5);
    printf("Aの補集合: \n");
    printIntArray(SD, length);
    printf("Bの補集合: \n");
    printIntArray(SD, length1);
    printf("Cの補集合: \n");
    printIntArray(SD, lenght2);

    return 0;
}
```

```
$ ./a.out
全体集合U: 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
集合A: 
1 3 5 7 9 
集合B: 
1 2 3 4 5 
集合C: 
0 2 4 6 8 
Aの補集合: 
1 3 5 7 9 
Bの補集合: 
1 3 5 7 9 
Cの補集合: 
1 3 5 7 9
```

なぜ、A,B,Cの補集合がすべて同じ結果で出力されるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SD`の内容を上書きしてしまったんです。

```
    int length=diff(SU,10,SA,5,SD);
    int length1=diff(SU,10,SB,5,SD);
    int lenght2=diff(SU,10,SC,5,SD);
```

複数の差集合を求めるには：

- 三つの結果アレイを用いて、差集合を算出します。

```
    int SD[1024] = { }; 
    int SD1[1024] = { };
    int SD2[1024] = { };
    int length=diff(SU,10,SA,5,SD);
    int length1=diff(SU,10,SB,5,SD1);
    int lenght2=diff(SU,10,SC,5,SD2);
    （略）
    printf("Aの補集合: \n");
    printIntArray(SD, length);
    printf("Bの補集合: \n");
    printIntArray(SD1, length1);
    printf("Cの補集合: \n");
    printIntArray(SD2, lenght2);
```

- 又は、同じ`SD`を兼用して、一つの差集合を計算、出力してから、次の差集合を計算します。

```
    int SD[1024] = { }; 
    int length=diff(SU,10,SA,5,SD);
    printf("Aの補集合: \n");
    printIntArray(SD, length);

    length=diff(SU,10,SB,5,SD);
    printf("Bの補集合: \n");
    printIntArray(SD, length);

    length=diff(SU,10,SC,5,SD);
    printf("Cの補集合: \n");
    printIntArray(SD, lenght);
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。複数の補集合を出力させるためには、毎度一つの補集合を計算、出力しまた計算するということは初めて知ったので、とても勉強になりました。